# Php getting ten's value

Tags: php, numbers

If I have values

2014 I need to get the 14,

2022 I need to get the 22,

2122 I need to get 122,

I could do:

```
$value = 2000 - $value;
```

But what if it's

1014? where I need to get the 14?

Is there any way to get the ten's value of any number? or 100's value? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is. Use modulus:

```
<?php 

echo 2014%1000;
echo 2022%1000;
echo 2122%1000;
echo 1014%1000;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is:

```
$result = $value % 1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

If they aren't necessarily numbers and you just want the two left values, you could also use:

[substr()](https://www.php.net/substr)

```
$result = substr($value, -2);    // returns last two characters
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, If you use % , you can get the reminder value , if your value = 1234 , then 1234 % 1000 will return 234 , similarly it goes on.

```
$value = 1022 ; // your value

$tens value = $value % 1000;

echo $tens value ;
```